# HTML5 video - incorrect Mime Types

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, html5-video

I've built a little website for my mate's birthday party and I've used FlareVideo jQuery plugin to load/play the video which includes a flash fallback. Now it seemed to work alright in Chrome, but in Firefox it shows a "No video with supported format and MIME type found." error. I've modified the **.htaccess** file with the following content:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(og[gv]|mp4|m4v|webm)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

But it didn't help. Also when typing in the video [URL](http://www.justo25.com/promo.mp4) directly it works alright. If anyone has any clue I'd appreciate it a lot!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding them to the apache mime.types file? Be sure to restart apache when you do.

BTW, the typical location is something like  /usr/local/apache/conf

I hope that helps you.

Take care.